# Storing a Timezone with Rails in PostgreSQL - what field type to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, timezone

I'm storing timezones in my database that I get via FB's api. The timezone looks like:

```
-7
```

What field should I be using in rails/PostgreSQL to store this value? String?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your timezone is always going to be an offset then use a `:decimal` (don't forget about places like Newfoundland Canada that are at UTC−3.5). Generally, timezones come in many different forms:

```
UTC-3.5
-7
America/Vancouver
```

So your safest bet would be a `:string`. The [Olson Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olson_database) is a good place to get an idea of the various timezone formats you'll come across.

Comment: a string is also a good choice for countries that follow Daylight Savings.